# Search in MongoDB array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array

I have some mongoDB documents with the following structure:

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
  [$id] => 50664339b3e7a7cf1c000001
)
[uid] => 1
  [name] => Alice
  [words] => 1
  [formatIds] => Array (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 4
  )
```

What I want to do is find all documents which has the value 1 in formatIds[ ]. I think it's possible to accomplish that. How can I do it in PHP?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the help. It works fine now. Here is how i wrote the search,

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$query = array('formatIds'=> "{$id}" );
$result = $stations_table->find($query); //where $stations_table = $db->stations;
```

Comment: There is a bug in you indent no ?

Comment: I dont think so.. I solved it finally..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB treats queries on array values the same way as queries on standard values, as per the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray).

Querying for `array('formatIds' => 1)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

As MongoDB "transform" array into multi value for a same key :

> $cursor = $mongo->base->collection->find(array('formatIds' => 1));

With correct definition of you mongo object and setting base/collection string.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you only want the documents or values that match your query or not.

If you don't mind pulling out the entire array and then searching client side for it you can of course use:

```
$c = $db->col->find(array('formatIds' => 1))
```

Since a 1-dimensional array in MongoDB can be searched like a single field.

But now to get only those that match your query since the above query will pick out all:

```
$db->command(array(
    'aggregate' => 'col',
    'pipeline' => array(
        array('$unwind' => "$formatIds"),
        array('$match' => array('formatIds' => 1)),
        array('$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$_id', 
            'formats' => array('$push' => '$formatIds'))
        )
    )
)
```

Use something like that.

This would give you a result of the `_id` being the `_id` of the document and a field of `formats` with only rows of the value `1` in the array.